# geographic database structure

Tags: mysql, database, elasticsearch

I've a geographic db in mysql with over 15M record. By now every record has a field `parent_id`: for example Tuscany has the `parent_id` of Italy etc.
It's a tree but mistructured

Sadly this structure isn't flexible at all for our needs:

1. get all leaves for a given node
2. get all the descendants of a node
3. get all the ancestors of a node
4. get the immediate children of a node

1 and 2 can be achieved with the nested set structure, 4 with the actual structure. I don't know how to deal with the 3rd

Sadly the nested set structure it is not efficient with reordering and adding nodes

So here the questions:

1. How would you structure it?
2. Would you keep using mysql? Better something else?
3. Do you gave any pro advice on how to move the actual db to the new one?

Moreover, the db infos must be aviable also through Elasticsearch, so do you think it's better to build and structure the db directly on it? If yes, how?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Do you have any resource on it? I don't even know what you're talking about XD

Comment: MySQL cannot do recursive common table expression queries, which is useful for hiearchical data. Is PostgreSQL an option? Also, check out structure of geonames databases, they are less hierarchical, as geo data is not very hierarchical

Comment: yeah PostgreSQL is an option! P.S. do you mean [this one](http://www.geonames.org/)? I think geo is very hierarchical, isn't it?

Comment: No it isn't. Some zip codes cross state boundaries. Which continent is Istanbul in? Which continent is Russia in?

Comment: Zipcodes is not really something into the equation right now (speaking for us). You're right on the second thing but I think it's a non problem. Istanbul is in Turkey that is in Asia. Russia is both in Asia and in Europe so we've to come out with a structure that allows for something like that. Do you have any resources on how recursive Cte work and implementation?